# Selectbox display "value" replace witht jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Exist any way to replace option display value?

[image]

I mean, here i need to replace "one"->"first option", "two"->"second", there are also already values also available.

**HTML**

```
<select id="selecttool">
    <option value="7">one</option>
    <option value="3">two</option>
    <option value="375">three</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selecttool").children().val("-79");

    if($("#selecttool").val('7')) {

    }
});
```

Here is my JSfiddle, so i tried to replace, but don't know how to insert value:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdebgnr/TrxD5/3/)

Comment: why can't you do it in the html itself

Comment: You want to replace 'one' with 'first option' and 'two' with 'second'?

Comment: are you working with any CMS?

Comment: Yes, and this is reason why i can't edit something for frontend area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your text to  the text() function as follows

```
$("#selecttool option[value='79']").text("label");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to the `text()` method for each option:

```
$('#selecttool option').text(function(){
    return this.value;        
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/TrxD5/8/)

---

**EDIT**

If you want 'custom text' you'll need to get it from somewhere, so create an array:

```
var vals = ['first option', 'second option', 'third option']
$('#selecttool option').text(function(i){
    return vals[i];        
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/TrxD5/10/)

---

**ANOTHER**

If you wanted to select on the text within the option:

```
$('#selecttool option:contains(one)').text('first option');
```

Comment: Thanke you, but i don't need to use values, i have to insert custom text, it's possible?

Comment: ha ha ha... thin air?

Comment: Simple manual to insert $('value 1').text('first item'); i hope you can understand what i mean?

Comment: So.. Something like [`$('option:contains(one)').text('first option');`](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/TrxD5/13/)

Comment: I was trying the same with each function but no idea could you place this as added answer.

Answer (score 0):

your way of selecting the element is wrong. you should select OPTION, not SELECT. 
like:

```
$('#selecttool option').eq(0).text("First Item"),
```

But, this will be very much mannual work, because you need to it one-by-one for all the options. So, if you have all the text, store it in an array as suggested **oGeez**, and then do a loop. like :

```
var labels = ["First Item", "Second Item", "last Item"];

$('#selecttool option').each(function(c, obj){
     $(obj).text(labels[c]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you can easily replace value with jquery like this

var value = $("#text").val(); // value = one use $("#text").text() if you are not on select box...
value = value.replace("1", "one");